# How to custom category template based on category?

Tags: theme-development, categories, customization

My blog have 2 categories: Photos and Texts.

I would like do customize the category template so that when it renders Photos post's, I want to show a thumbnail gallery and when it renders Texts post's, I want show only the excerpt.

There is an way to do this without hardcoding on category.php? Or, at least, how is the best way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create [category templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates); i.e. category-photos.php and category-texts.php; starting with a copy of the code from category.php. you will still need to hard-code the changes in each template.

Comment: I tried this plugin and does the same I just don't really need to edit those files and the best thing is I can use my page builder to design my category pages.
http://magnigenie.com/product/wordpress-custom-taxonomy-category-pages/